# Add only one XML element into combobox

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, visual-studio

I am making a small application with some checkboxes and filtering options, in Visual Studio WPF using c#.

For my data, I have an XML document with various Locations that looks like this:

```
<Cities>
    <Location>
        <Name>Gava</Name>
        <City>Barcelona</City>
        <Community>Catalonia</Community>
        <Checked>False</Checked>
      </Location>
      <Location>
        <Name>Castelldefels</Name>
        <City>Barcelona</City>
        <Community>Catalonia</Community>
        <Checked>False</Checked>
      </Location>
      <Location>
        <Name>San Juan</Name>
        <City>Alicante</City>
        <Community>Valencia</Community>
        <Checked>False</Checked>
      </Location>
      <Location>
        <Name>Benidorm</Name>
        <City>Alicante</City>
        <Community>Valencia</Community>
        <Checked>False</Checked>
      </Location>
      <Location>
        <Name>Sagunto</Name>
        <City>Valencia</City>
        <Community>Valencia</Community>
        <Checked>False</Checked>
      </Location>
</Cities>
```

With this, I populate a listview with checkboxes with this function:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");

private void PopulateLocationList()
        {
            foreach(var elem in xdoc.Descendants("Location"))
            {
                ListView1.Items.Add(new CheckBox { Content = elem.Element("Name").Value, IsChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(elem.Element("Checked").Value) });
            }
        }
```

What I want to do now, is to populate a `ComboBox`with the `City` names, but that the City value appears only once.
I tried the same function above changing some names like this:

```
foreach(var elem in xdoc.Descendants("Location"))
            {
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = elem.Element("City").Value });
            }
```

but what this does is get all the `City` values and fill the `ComboBox`. What I want is if there's a repeated value (for example two Barcelona), to only show one in the ComboBox. I just can't think of how to do that.

Thanks in advance for anyone that replies. I am still a beginner in all this programming thing and am not recieving formal training, just following tutorials on the internet, and sometimes it gets tricky like this.

**Edit**: I am aware I could do this manually in the Designer or even using a separate part in my xml document just for the cities, but I want to do this like this so I can reuse some i elements, like the Listview and the Comboboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put the distinct inside of the foreach for readability.. but it could be on the end of the `xdoc` statement, after the [**Select**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1).

```
var cities = xdoc.Descendants("Location").Select(o => o.Element("City").Value);

foreach (var city in cities.Distinct())
{
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = city });
}
```

// o => o.Elements is the same as the following

```
void MainMethod()
{
    var cities = xdoc.Descendants("Location").Select(SelectCity);

    foreach (var city in cities.Distinct())
    {
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = city });
    }
}

string SelectCity(XElement location)
{
    return location.Element("City").Value;
}
```

Look into linq statements (Can be quite brain burning). Nice little cheatsheet page: https://linqsamples.com/

Think of the select as a foreach which just returns an element. The o => is you saying the same as "var city in cities" after the lambda symbol '=>' is just what you want returned. (This is not actually what it's doing, but will make it easier to understand for this example).

Comment: o is just an alias, same as "var city" in the foreach. So o can be location, so location => location.Element("City").

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I tried it and what I get now is ComboBoxItems that have only a letter though

Comment: Sounds like the Select is only returning a single item... which it normally doesn't. So by the time you get to your foreach your actually looping over a string. This will be why your getting a character through.

Comment: Ah, I had tried it with SelectMany instead of Select. With Select it works fine! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: That was my bad. I re-read it the first time and realised I used the wrong method :D